# how to get value from promise resolved?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise

the snippet is

```
var name = firebase.firestore().collection('users_info').doc(uid).get().then(async function(doc) { 
        const usr = await doc.data().name;
        console.log(usr);
        return  await(usr); 
});
console.log(name);
```

name logs the below

`Promise {<pending>}
__proto__: Promise
[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved"
[[PromiseValue]]: "hello"`

and usr logs the hello, please help me get the value in name.

Comment: All `async` functions return a promise - always.  So, the caller of your function needs to use `.then()` or `await` to get the value from the returned promise.  There is no way around this.  Also, `return await(usr)` does nothing useful.  It should just be `return usr`.  Your function is returning a promise, regardless of whether you do `return usr` or `return await usr`.  The `async` function will make the return value be the resolved value of the promise.  Perhaps useful to know that when your function hits the first `await`, that's the point where the function returns the promise.

Answer (score 0):

You want to chain a then/catch to resolve the name promise  or you can wrap the entire block you have in an async/await, and invoke the function:

```
            async function fetchData() {
                try {
                    var name = await firebase.firestore().collection("users_info").doc(uid).get();
                    const usr = await doc.data().name;
                    console.log(usr);
                    console.log(name);
                    return usr;
                } catch(e) {
                    console.log(e);
                }

            }
```